# PostgreSQL open JSONB column with slashes

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

How is it possible to open the JSONB column where JSONB string with slashes?

```
"{\"id\":\"c39fe0f5f9b7c89b005bf3491f2a2ce1\",\"token\":\"c39fe0f5f9b7c89b005bf3491f2a2ce1\",\"line_items\":[{\"id\":32968150843480,\"properties\":{},\"quantity\":2,\"variant_id\":32968150843480,\"key\":\"32968150843480:4a6f6b7d19c7aef119af2cd909f429f1\",\"discounted_price\":\"40.00\",\"discounts\":[],\"gift_card\":false,\"grams\":0,\"line_price\":\"80.00\",\"original_line_price\":\"80.00\",\"original_price\":\"40.00\",\"price\":\"40.00\",\"product_id\":4638774493272,\"sku\":\"36457537-mud-yellow-28\",\"taxable\":false,\"title\":\"Knee Length Summer Shorts - Camel / 28\",\"total_discount\":\"0.00\",\"vendor\":\"Other\",\"discounted_price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"line_price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"original_line_price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"total_discount_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"0.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"0.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}}}],\"note\":null,\"updated_at\":\"2022-03-15T13:24:02.787Z\",\"created_at\":\"2022-03-15T13:23:31.912Z\",\"controller\":\"custom_webhooks\",\"action\":\"store_data\",\"custom_webhook\":{\"id\":\"c39fe0f5f9b7c89b005bf3491f2a2ce1\",\"token\":\"c39fe0f5f9b7c89b005bf3491f2a2ce1\",\"line_items\":[{\"id\":32968150843480,\"properties\":{},\"quantity\":2,\"variant_id\":32968150843480,\"key\":\"32968150843480:4a6f6b7d19c7aef119af2cd909f429f1\",\"discounted_price\":\"40.00\",\"discounts\":[],\"gift_card\":false,\"grams\":0,\"line_price\":\"80.00\",\"original_line_price\":\"80.00\",\"original_price\":\"40.00\",\"price\":\"40.00\",\"product_id\":4638774493272,\"sku\":\"36457537-mud-yellow-28\",\"taxable\":false,\"title\":\"Knee Length Summer Shorts - Camel / 28\",\"total_discount\":\"0.00\",\"vendor\":\"Other\",\"discounted_price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"line_price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"original_line_price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"80.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"price_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"40.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}},\"total_discount_set\":{\"shop_money\":{\"amount\":\"0.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"},\"presentment_money\":{\"amount\":\"0.0\",\"currency_code\":\"USD\"}}}],\"note\":null,\"updated_at\":\"2022-03-15T13:24:02.787Z\",\"created_at\":\"2022-03-15T13:23:31.912Z\"}}"
```

this real JSONB column
[image]

I can not find any example of how to deal with this type of JSONB

Comment: Looks like a problem with your tooling. What tool do you use?

Comment: I use PG Admin 4

Comment: What options do you have to not display all these quotes " ? Because it's just a problem with displaying the results, in your database everything is fine.

Comment: I just need to extract data from jsonb to columns and rows like a simple table

Comment: All these slashes and extra quotes, are a result of PG Admin4. Change it's display setting, if possible, or use a different tool. And turning a JSON object in a row/column layout, can be done using the json-functions in PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens  of the many problems pgAdmin has, I think this is not one.

Comment: No, it is valid, just inconvenient.  Take his string, put it in the middle of `select '...'::jsonb;` and you get back the same thing you started with.

Comment: @jjanes: Yeah, you're right, didn't know that, learned something new! I never had such json garbage in my database, could be luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever is inserting your data is screwing it up.  It is taking the string representation of a JSON object and stuffing that into a JSON string scalar.  You need to fix that or it will just keep happening.

To fix what is already there, you need to extract the real PostgreSQL string out of the JSON string, then cast that to JSONB.  Extracting a JSON string can be done unintuitively with `#>>'{}'`, or even less intuitively with `->>0`.

```
select (data#>>'{}')::jsonb from table_name.
```

Of course you should fix it permanently, not just do it on the fly all the time, which is both slow and confusing.

```
update table_name set data=(data#>>'{}')::jsonb;
```

Of course fixing the tool which screws this up in the first place, and fixing the historical data, need to be done in a coordinated fashion or you will have a glorious mess on your hands.

Comment: Using a BEFORE trigger to clean up the incoming mess could help to get the problem under control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong formatted string in jsonb field. You can try fix it in next way:

```
select trim(both '"' from replace(data::varchar, '\"', '"'))::jsonb data from tbl;
```

[PostgreSQL JSONB online](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/9a0f7eb50442ed7c34c783d582fc9520/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This method does not work in any situation. For example, I get error like :```ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json``` ,   CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...ghgate Junior School Tracksuit - 24\\"","...